# How to integrate such kind of source generator into CMake build chain?

Tags: cmake

I'm writing a C++ project which use a code generator (perl xsubpp). It generates C/C++ source code from XS file. As xsubpp sometimes produce incomplete output file, I want to have it run before the actual binary target is built, regardless there exists generated source file.

I can find out two ways to achieve it:

```
# the target is always out-of-date, so the command is always run
add_custom_target(...)
add_library(lib_name ...)
add_dependencies(lib_name ...)
```

and

```
add_library(lib_name ...)
# the command is always run before lib_name is build
add_custom_command(TARGET lib_name PRE_BUILD ...)
```

However, none of them works, because `add_library()` checks source file at configure time. The source file must either exist, or as an output target of `add_custom_command()`.

For the first way, the `add_custom_target()` don't have the concept of output target; and for the second way, the `add_custom_command()` is used as an auxiliary of *lib_name*, which also don't have the concept of output target.

Comment: Using a generated header/source should not be a problem, as the source will be marked as GENERATED and thus safe to use in add_library (this is at least what I get from reading the CMake FAQ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me. I hope that this is what you want.

The source (foo.cpp) is re-generated every time I run make.

src/C_generated/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_custom_target(generate_foo 
  touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script.sh
  COMMENT "add_custom_target, touch script.sh"
)

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
  TARGET generate_foo
  COMMAND   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script.sh
  ARGS      "some args"
  COMMENT "custom commands, executing script.sh"
    )

set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.cpp PROPERTIES GENERATED 1)

add_library(LIBC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.cpp)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(LIBC generate_foo)
```

src/C_generated/script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running script.sh"

echo "#include <stdio.h>" > foo.cpp
echo "/*" >> foo.cpp
date >> foo.cpp
echo "*/" >> foo.cpp
echo >> foo.cpp
echo "void testC()" >> foo.cpp
echo "{" >> foo.cpp
echo "  printf(\"Generated source.\");" >> foo.cpp
echo "}" >> foo.cpp
```

Main CMakeLists.txt which combines generated source with non-generated source:

```
project(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(src)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src/A)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src/B)
# Generated files only.
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src/C_generated)

# Combine the different libraries into one.
add_library(TESTLIB STATIC src/dummy.c)

ADD_DEPENDENCIES(TESTLIB LIBA)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(TESTLIB LIBB)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(TESTLIB LIBC)

GET_TARGET_PROPERTY(LIBA_LOC LIBA LOCATION)
GET_TARGET_PROPERTY(LIBB_LOC LIBB LOCATION)
GET_TARGET_PROPERTY(LIBC_LOC LIBC LOCATION)

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(TESTLIB PROPERTIES STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS "${LIBA_LOC} ${LIBB_LOC} ${LIBC_LOC}")
```

Download this example from:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68798379/cmake-code-generator.tar.bz2